# Is there any way to retain/put default textarea content without any white space padding in laravel?

Tags: laravel, textarea, retain

I am displaying Textarea content with the data retrieved from the database in Laravel. But, I am getting some additional spaces. Is there any way to remove the spaces?
Here's my code. I even tried trimming the white spaces if there are any.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" type="text" rows="5" style="color: black; text-align: left;">
@if(old('details'))
{{old('details')}}
@else
{{trim($data[0]->address, " ")}}
@endif
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

That whitespace is most likely not caused by your data but because of newlines and blade. Change to

```
@if(old('details'))
<textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" type="text" rows="5" style="color: black; text-align: left;">{{old('details')}}</textarea>
@else
<textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" type="text" rows="5" style="color: black; text-align: left;">{{trim($data[0]->address, " ")}}</textarea>
@endif
```

and see if that helps.

If you don't want to repeat/duplicate the `<textarea...>` part you could make it a [component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components).